# Connected vertices cause problem with bevel

Tags: modeling, vertices, bevel

I am having issues because my object is connected to other vertices so when I try to bevel edges I get messed up bevel:

Here are edges that connected vertecies:
[image]

Now when I try to bevel edges of my object:
[image]

Is there some way to fix this? Here is link to download my blend file: [https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6be8543fe48815e3127a7e3622af155020230130211637/7904df](https://we.tl/t-NPhd4wSy1p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable Face Orientation you'll see that part of that ring has inverted normals (coloured red). Select <kbd>All</kbd> in Edit mode and then <kbd>Shift-N</kbd> to recalculate the normals. You'll then find that bevelling works correctly.

[image]